# building a static version of QT Library

Tags: qt, qt4

I would like to build a static version of QT Library for X11 like shown in the doc [Deploying an Application on X11 Platforms](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/deployment-x11.html) but I am stuck at the first step.

where it says : 
cd /path/to/Qt 
 ./configure -static -prefix /path/to/Qt  
 make sub-src

1) Where is the path/to/Qt.  Is this a path to libs or executables or what?  In /usr/bin I have: qt3to4, qtconfig-qt4, qtcreator and qmake-qt4.   In /usr/include/qt4/Qt I have a whole bunch of header files.  In /usr/lib I have all the shared libraries.

2)when I type : "./configure -static -prefix /path/to/Qt" 
 I get "bash: ./configure: No such file or directory"

Comment: Download the source code and unpack it in a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `/path/to/Qt` is where you unpackaged the sources, maybe `~/src/qt` or something.

The second `/path/to/Qt` is where you want the *installed* build to live, say, `/usr/local/qt` or `/opt/qt` or something.

And if `bash` complains then it means that you did not change into the directory with your sources.

Comment: thanks,  I did not build Qt, but simply ran sudo apt-get install so I guess I dont have it and need to download it.

Comment: Are you sure you really, really need a static build?  Running on a different distro?  Can't you just build for that?